# How can Gmail still access yahoo mails using OAuth when yahoo has disabled this feature

Tags: oauth, gmail-api, yahoo-mail

I am trying to develop an email client application but yahoo mails are not accessible as they have removed the scope of email from the developer console at the time of app creation on Yahoo developer console. 
But how can gmail and few other email clients are able to achieve this.

Comment: yes i too looking for the solution. Did you find any?

Comment: I tried this : "https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/?api=mail" 
With the msg: Your application has been created successfully!
The Client ID and Client Secret below will allow you to write an application that interacts with OAuth-enabled Yahoo APIs including Mail API. But its not working.